# Strange error @ Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

this:

```
Polygon::Polygon(const Polygon & polygon) {
    for (vector<Point*>::iterator it = polygon._points.begin(); it != _points.end(); it++)
        _points.push_back(*it);
}
```

gives me an error of

```
C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Point *>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Point *>>>
```

While this works:

```
Polygon::Polygon(const Polygon & polygon) {
    vector<Point*> points = polygon._points;
    for (vector<Point*>::iterator it = points.begin(); it != _points.end(); it++)
        _points.push_back(*it);
}
```

Comment: Your mixing iterators to two different objects.  One is to the polygon function argument and one is to the _points which I assume is a member variable.

Comment: it != _points.end(); shouldn't that be it!= polygon._points.end()?

Comment: u're right, but what causing the error is 

vector<Point*>::iterator it = polygon._points.begin()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking a `const Polygon` as an argument. On the first case, your iterator is therefore const. On the second case, you're assigning the const polygon.vector into a local, non-const vector, which makes it possible to get a non-const iterator.

Take a look at what your code is actually doing: you're taking a polygon that you promise not to modify, and trying to insert points into it. Since that's what you're doing, better drop the const from the argument.